# How to make a RecyclerView adapter for a data model with nested lists

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listobject

Given a data model with a list of objects that have their own lists as properties:

```
private ObservableArrayList<BasProduct> basProducts = new ObservableArrayList<>();

//the model BasProduct have below attribute
public List<String> newOrderNotes;
public List<BasGoods> basGoodses;
```

how do I make a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that is based on this data?

Answer (score 1):

Your `RecyclerView` list view is one-dimensional.  Your list model is two-dimensional.  So you need to have a list adapter that flattens your two-dimensional model into a one-dimensional model.

So let's say you have this model:

```
BasProduct[0]
    OrderNote[0]
    OrderNote[1]
    BasGoods[0]
    BasGoods[1]
BasProduct[1]
    OrderNote[0]
    OrderNote[1]
    BasGoods[0]
    BasGoods[1]
```

i.e. you have two products, each product has two items in both of their lists.

Now you just have to turn that into this:

```
[0]    BasProduct[0]
[1]        OrderNote[0]
[2]        OrderNote[1]
[3]        BasGoods[0]
[4]        BasGoods[1]
[5]    BasProduct[1]
[6]        OrderNote[0]
[7]        OrderNote[1]
[8]        BasGoods[0]
[9]        BasGoods[1]
```

There are lots of ways to do this, the trick is to design a way so that you don't write obfuscated code with lots of bugs hiding in it.

What I did was to use `ExpandableListAdapter` as sort of a template and build from there.  So I wrote implementations for `getGroupCount()` and `getChildCount()`.  Then I implemented `getItemCount()` using those methods:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

       int count = 0;
       int groupCount = getGroupCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
           count++;
           if (mGroupExpanded[i]) {
                count += getChildCount(i);
           }
       }

       return count;
    }
```

You can see in my code I have a boolean array of group-expanded flags.  I made my `RecyclerView` have expandable groups, so this meant more code for keeping track of expanded/collapsed states.

Following the same pattern, I split binding into `onBindGroupViewHolder()` and `onBindChildViewHolder()`, then implemented `onBindViewHolder()` using those methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int pos = 0;
        int groupCount = getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
            if (pos == position) {
                onBindGroupViewHolder(holder, i);
                return;
            }
            pos++;
            if (mGroupExpanded[i]) {
                int childCount = getChildCount(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
                    if (pos == position) {
                       onBindChildViewHolder(holder, i, j);
                       return;
                    }
                    pos++;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't determine group/child for raw position = " + position);
    }
```

Then the last piece you need is a way to map the flattened position returned by `getAdapterPosition()` back to the group position and child position:

```
    private int[] getGroupChildPosition(int position) {

        // positions[0] is group position
        // positions[1] is child position, -1 means it's a group
        int[] positions = new int[2];
        int current = 0;
        int groupCount = getGroupCount();
        for (int currentGroup = 0; currentGroup < groupCount; currentGroup++) {
            if (current == position) {
                positions[0] = currentGroup;
                positions[1] = -1;
                return positions;
            }
            current++;
            if (mGroupExpanded[i]) {
                int childCount = getChildCount(i);
                for (int currentChild = 0; currentChild < childCount; currentChild++) {
                    if (current == position) {
                        positions[0] = currentGroup;
                        positions[1] = currentChild;
                        return positions;
                    }
                    current++;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't determine group/child for raw position = " + position);
    }
```

You can do it differently.  For example you can make a `Map` – actually a `SparseArray` – that maps the flattened positions to the group/child positions, or even the group/child model items themselves.

All that iteration is a lot of overhead.  I'm just showing how to handle flattening a list in a way that is very simple to understand.

So in sum: Your data is two-dimensional.  The list on your device is one-dimensional.  Think about what your data should look like on the device and write an adapter that does that.

Comment: List<BasGoods> has List<String>, and have to use RecyclerView to add xml to rander

Comment: i really liked your answer but am facing issues in actually implementing it. can you please provide a link for some sample code?

Comment: although the proposed solution is good for simple case, but it introduces too much complexity while implementing getItemViewType() and choosing different views for head and child layout. Seems like best possible solution is to use ExpandableListview for 2D lists handling.